# Getting all splits of numeric sequence in R

Tags: r, list, recursion, vector, sequence

I'm trying to get all the possible splits of a sequence `[1:n]` in R. E.g.:

```
getSplits(0,3)
```

Should return all possible splits of the sequence 123, in other words (in a list of vectors):

```
[1] 1
[2] 1 2
[3] 1 2 3
[4] 1 3
[5] 2
[6] 2 3
[7] 3
```

Now I've created a function which does get to these vectors recursively, but having trouble combining them into one as above. My function is:

```
getSplits <- function(currentDigit, lastDigit, split) {
  splits=list();
  for (nextDigit in currentDigit: lastDigit)
  {
    currentSplit <- c(split, c(nextDigit));
    print(currentSplit);
    if(nextDigit < lastDigit) {
      possibleSplits = c(list(currentSplit), getSplits(nextDigit+1, lastDigit, currentSplit));
    }else{
      possibleSplits = currentSplit;
    }
    splits <- c(splits, list(possibleSplits));
  }
  return(splits);
}
```

Where printing each currentSplit results in all the right vectors I need, but somehow the final returnt list (splits) nests them into deeper levels of lists, returning:

```
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[1]][[3]]
[1] 1 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2 3


[[3]]
[1] 3
```

For the corresponding function call `getSplits(1, 3, c())`.

If anyone could help me out on getting this to work the way I described above, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: No need for semi colons in your code. Also, if splits is already a list, then you probably just want `c(splits, possibleSplits)`. Finally, you can do something with an `lapply` over `1:3` using `combn` as the function to produce this. I'm too busy at the moment, but similar questions exist on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### character vector output

Try `combn`:

```
k <- 3
s <- unlist(lapply(1:k, combn, x = k, toString))
s
## [1] "1"       "2"       "3"       "1, 2"    "1, 3"    "2, 3"    "1, 2, 3"
```

### data frame output

If you would prefer that the output be in the form of a data frame:

```
read.table(text = s, header = FALSE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE, col.names = 1:k)
```

giving:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1 NA NA
2  2 NA NA
3  3 NA NA
4  1  2 NA
5  1  3 NA
6  2  3 NA
7  1  2  3
```

### list output

or a list:

```
lapply(s, function(x) scan(textConnection(x), quiet = TRUE, sep = ","))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 1 3

[[6]]
[1] 2 3

[[7]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

**Update:** Have incorporated improvement mentioned in comments as well as one further simplification and also added data frame and list output.

Comment: I think this can be shortened to `unlist(lapply(1:k, function(m) combn(k, m, FUN = toString)))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach:

```
f <- function(nums) sapply(1:length(nums), function(x) t(combn(nums, m = x)))
f(1:3)
```

This yields

```
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
```

Answer (score 3):

The OP is looking for the [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of `c(1,2,3)`. There are several packages that will quickly get you this in one line. Using the package `rje`, we have:

```
library(rje)
powerSet(c(1,2,3))
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 3

[[6]]
[1] 1 3

[[7]]
[1] 2 3

[[8]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

... and with `iterpc`:

```
library(iterpc)
getall(iterpc(c(2,1,1,1), 3, labels = 0:3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    2
[3,]    0    0    3
[4,]    0    1    2
[5,]    0    1    3
[6,]    0    2    3
[7,]    1    2    3
```

More generally,

```
n <- 3
getall(iterpc(c(n-1,rep(1, n)), n, labels = 0:n)) ## same as above
```